# Should we allow questions on how to self-publish?

Tags: discussion, faq, on-topic-definition

If a writer decides to go the route of self-publishing, it is unlikely they would know what steps to take to go about doing it. With that in mind, should we allow questions that ask for advice or guidance on how to get started or what steps to take? This should apply to any venue in which they choose to publish, whether it be subsidy publishing, print on demand, or e-books.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, we should, and we do.  According to the FAQ the publishing process is on-topic, and that includes self-publishing.  We even have an entire tag devoted to it, [self-publishing](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/self-publishing).  There are many examples that are either directly about or touch on self-publishing:

- [Publishing and selling e-books](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/1002/publishing-and-selling-ebooks)
- [Is it wise to publish a novel as an e-book and how would I do it?](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/3162/is-it-wise-to-publish-a-novel-as-an-e-book-and-how-would-i-do-it)
- [Can I ask CreateSpace not to add a barcode to my cover?](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/3270/can-i-ask-createspace-to-not-add-a-barcode-to-my-cover)
- [Can I ePublish my out-of-print history book?](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/2595/can-i-epublish-my-out-of-print-history-book)
- ..and many, many more

Comment: I have seen most of those questions, but they seem to be more about whether or not a writer should self-publish or they are asking something more specific about self-publishing. I was wondering if it would be considered appropriate for someone to ask about how to go about doing it.

Comment: @Steven, my vote would be for yes.

Answer (score 4):

I am a massive supporter of self-publishing and have extensive experience of the way that self-pub works, its advantages and its limitations. People aren't asking the questions and I have no real questions about it at present.

I don't see any reason why if people were to ask about self-publishing I shouldn't have some advice or experience to offer and I'm sure there are others about too.