# Should we allow questions on where to self-publish?

Tags: discussion, on-topic-definition

Following my question on [whether questions about HOW to self-publish are on-topic](https://writers.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/345/should-we-allow-questions-on-how-to-self-publish), I am wondering if it is appropriate to allow questions asking WHERE a writer should go to either seek help with self-publishing or to do it himself. For example, the names of specific subsidy publishers, offering a suggestion to use CreateSpace for POD, or suggesting Kindle Direct Publishing and Smashwords for e-books.

Comment: I have edited your tags.  On meta all questions about what is and isn't on-topic should have the tag on-topic-definition.  What the particular item is that is or isn't on-topic needn't be tagged.

Comment: @Dori - good point....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe this can generally be on-topic, but may be unhelpful.  For example someone asking "What is the best place to self-publish a fantasy novel/collection of poetry/book on the history of religion?" would be on-topic.  On the other hand, someone asking "Here is a specific outline of my novel, where is the best fit for publishing it?" is treading dangerously close to the "Too Localized" close reason.  Specific questions that are looking for advice on one author's too-personal circumstances, other than critique questions, are just not helpful to the site and the internet in general.

As per the network-wide guidelines, if someone from a specific self-publishing company chooses to answer a question, he or she would be required to disclose their affiliation with the company to avoid being accused of astro-turfing.

Also in answer to questions about self-publishing a valid, acceptable answer should always be "You shouldn't do it, and here's why" if indeed the whys provide a compelling case.