# "where to publish?"--on-topic or no?

Tags: discussion, on-topic-definition

Can I ask for recommendations of where to submit pieces I've written? Obviously I can google for "creative writing journals" or whatever myself, so I'm more interested in what journals (or whatever) are considered good, especially in a particular genre (eg scifi).

EDIT: I found this:
[Should we allow questions on where to self-publish?](https://writers.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/346/should-we-allow-questions-on-where-to-self-publish?rq=1) which seems pretty close, so unless someone says not to, I might just give it a whirl and see what happens.

Comment: I think the more on point answer to questions of this sort is, why do you not already know where the good stuff in your field is being published? Aren't you reading it?

Comment: @MarkBaker Hm, fair point. OTOH, where good writing is published isn't quite the same as what's "considered good," and that's harder to evaluate--like how which colleges are "considered good" isn't the same as where you can get a good education.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if those kinds of questions are or should be on topic, but I always, when I read them, want to reply with the following:

Many aspiring writers are very much self-involved and completely unaware of where they are in the world of fiction publishing. They are, to use an analogy, like [Donald Trump asking his aides what the START treaty was](http://www.independent.co.uk/news/world/americas/us-politics/donald-trump-new-start-russia-vladimir-putin-nuclear-treaty-phone-call-latest-a7572281.html). Obviously you can be ignorant and still become president, and you certainly become a bestselling author without being widely read, but when you look at bestselling authors (and successful politicians) they usually are members of their community – of Science Fiction writers, for example – and know what goes on in that community. They know who the established publishers are and which authors are up and coming. They know the current trends among their audience and who doesn't get along with whom. Because writing professionally requires an expertise that is no different than the expertise of other professionals and requires you stay on top of current events just like a physician has to know new and better treatments.

So the answer to your and similar questions is always that you need to become part of your community. You need to network and subscribe to publications that cover the news in your genre. For SF, you would read something like *[Locus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locus_(magazine))* and be a member in something like the [SFWA](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Science_Fiction_and_Fantasy_Writers_of_America). Or you read John Scalzi's [blog](http://whatever.scalzi.com/) and become friends with other SF writers from your area.

Answer (score 1):

Specific recommendations will be out of date in a few months or years. Asking for recommendations isn't as future-proof as asking for criteria - in other words, rather than "please recommend X" one can ask "what should I look for in X?"

Related: 
- [Q&A is Hard, Let's Go Shopping!](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/)

Comment: Would they go out-of-date that much *faster* than any other aspect of publishing advice?

Comment: @MissMonicaE - That's the idea. Asking what to look for rather than asking for sites that are good, so the answers stay more current. (Clarified my a answer to show this better.)